# Greenplum gpseginstall asking for "cluster password access"

Tags: greenplum

I'm installing greenplum database on my desktop computer following the official installation guide. When I'm executing

```
# gpseginstall -f hostfile_exkeys -u gpadmin -p P@$$word
```

it asks me to provide cluster password access:

```
[root@sm403-08 greenplum-db-4.2.1.0]# gpseginstall -f hostfile_exkeys -uyang -par0306
20120506:05:59:33:012887 gpseginstall:sm403-08:root-[INFO]:-Installation Info:
link_name None
binary_path /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.1.0
binary_dir_location /usr/local
binary_dir_name greenplum-db-4.2.1.0
20120506:05:59:33:012887 gpseginstall:sm403-08:root-[INFO]:-check cluster password access
*** Enter password for localhost-2: 
*** Enter password for localhost-2: 
*** Enter password for localhost-2: 
*** Enter password for localhost-2: 
*** Enter password for localhost-2:
```

This is what my hostfile_exkeys file looks like:

```
localhost
localhost-1
localhost-2
```

since I only have one machine.

A similar post on the web (http://www.topix.com/forum/com/greenplum/TSDQHMJ6M7I9D0A44) says:

*"I had the same error and I discovered that it was because I had set sshd to refuse root login. You must edit your sshd configuration and permit root login for gpseginstall to work. Hope that helps!"*

But I have tried to modify my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to let it permit root login:

```
# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
```

and restarted sshd:

```
Stopping sshd:                                             [FAILED]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

but nothing works; the gpseginstall program is still asking for password.

I have tried all the passwords I can ever think of, root, gpadmin, my own user's password, but none of them works. What am I expected to do to get it work?

**Update:** It seems that the problem lies in installing the Greenplum community edition on a single node. Is there anyone who has some experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I'm installing Greenplum database on a single node, so don't have to do the gpseginstall step. This is used to install Greenplum on all segments from the master host.

Comment: The docs say otherwise.  At what point is the user gpadmin to be created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable password auth.

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Then    `service sshd restart`

Answer (score 0):

I will be glad if it helps someone who is trying to install greenplum in cluster mode.

```
#installing greenplum cluster steps
# first add entires for all servers and interfaces in your /etc/hosts
# gpdb01- master
# gpdb02 - secondary master
# gpdb03 , gpdb04 - data nodes

#setup ssh between all machines
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id gpdb02
ssh-copy-id gpdb03
ssh-copy-id gpdb04

# also add entries for the interfaces
vi /etc/hosts

172.12.13.14 gpdb01
172.12.13.14 gpdb01-1
172.12.13.14 gpdb01-2

172.12.13.15 gpdb02
172.12.13.15 gpdb02-1
172.12.13.15 gpdb02-2

172.12.13.16 gpdb03
172.12.13.16 gpdb03-1
172.12.13.16 gpdb03-2

172.12.13.17 gpdb04
172.12.13.17 gpdb04-1
172.12.13.17 gpdb04-2


# enable RootLogin and PasswordAuthentication on all servers
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart

#create your hostkey file

gpdb01
gpdb01-1
gpdb01-2
gpdb02
gpdb02-1
gpdb02-2
gpdb03
gpdb03-1
gpdb03-2
gpdb04
gpdb04-1
gpdb04-2


# run the gpseg installer
gpseginstall -f hostfile_exkeys -u gpadmin -p P@$$word
```